# Synchronizing my iPad photos to my iMac (2017) with an external SSD

Tags: macos, ipad, imac, photos, ssd

My internal SSD drive was getting full so I purchased a plug-in, external SSD.

Will I be able to sync my photos to my iPad’s now that I’ve done this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I have a M1 Mac mini that needed an external drive to house the full photos library.

Nothing that worked with the library located on the internal storage / boot volume stops when you relocate the library to an external directly attached drive.

I don't recommend a NAS drive for photos library, but some people have made it work. Direct attached drives is my recommendation for reliability and speed and full function.

Here is the official guide on how to set this up:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/108345